# Pullback in differential graded algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Suppose that $(A, d_A),(B,d_B),(C,d_C)$ are (unbounded) differential graded
algebras and that $f:A \to C$ and $g:B \to C$ are homomorphisms of differential graded algebras. What is (or how do we compute) the pullback:

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
A \times_C B & \longrightarrow & B \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow\\
A & \longrightarrow & C
\end{array}
$$

in the category of differential graded algebras? Is it done differently with commutative diff. graded algebras?

Moreover is there a 'standard reference' for pullbacks or all kinds of 'common'
(co)limits? Not very time economical if everyone computes them by herself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pullbacks (in fact, all limits) in categories of algebraic structures are created by the forgetful functor to $\mathsf{Set}$. Such basic facts can be found in Mac Lane's CWM, but you can also just prove it. The category of differential graded algebras is of course algebraic.

Thus, we have $(A \times_C B)_n = A_n \times_{C_n} B_n$, with componentwise operations, and componentwise differential, i.e. $d(a,b) = (da,db)$.

For differential graded algebras, I think there is also the notion of a *homotopy pullback*. This is more complicated, but also more natural for some applications in homotopical algebra.

Comment: So $A_n \times_{C_n} B_n$ is then $\{(a^n,b^n)\in A_n\oplus B_n\;|\;f(a^n)=g(b^n)\}$ and the product? Is it $(a^n_1,b^n_1)\cdot(a^n_2,b^n_2)=(a^n_1 a^n_2,b^n_1 b^n_2)$?

Comment: Yes, everything is componentwise. (And you may just write $(a,b)$ instead of $(a^n,b^n)$.)